# Removing www from url in IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-6

I have an SSL certificate setup for www.mydomain.com. I'm having a strange issue in IIS 6. When I navigate to www.mydomain.com everything works fine. Since the www. part is what my ssl certificate is registered under I get no issues. Hwoever, all of my links in my site take me to mydomain.com/mylink which causes a cetificate error because it's not prefixed with www. My website is ASP.Net and all my links are relative to the root (in other words I'm specifying ~/mylink and not hardcoding the mydomain.com part). Any idea why IIS or asp.net is removing www from all my links?

Comment: Something fishy is going on here...  ASP.NET shouldn't be including any kind of hostname (www.mydomain.com OR mydomain.com) in server-generated URLs prefixed with ~.

Comment: It's important to be aware that if you don't use a www (or some other subdomain) then all cookies will be submitted to every subdomain amd you won't be able to have a cookie-less subdomain for serving static content thus reducing the amount of data sent back and forth between the browser and the server. Something you might later come to regret: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1637428313

Answer (score 0):

You could setup another website specifically for the non-www one and force it to redirect back to the www site.

Then setup logs in a different location and see if that lets you find the offending pages/links.

Otherwise you may have to use some link checking script to see if any links are coming out incorrectly. Normally, you should be using '~' in your links so that they get resolved by ASP.NET. This should give you an app relative root which shouldn't give you this error.

So you may have a few 'http...' links in there.

Failing that, I can't think of another reason!

HTH anyway.